# Mocha Tests Not Showing Up

Tags: node.js, express, tdd, mocha.js, chai

I am working through *Web Development with Node & Express*, Chapter 5 (Quality Assurance). I have set up Mocha and Chai, but the tests are not showing up, even when I add the ?tests=1 onto the url.

meadowlark.js (main entry point):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({ defaultLayout: 'main' });

// express handles normalizing url

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.locals.showTests = app.get('env') !== 'production' && req.query.text === '1';
   next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.render('home');
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
   res.render('about');
});

// 404 catch-all handler (middleware)
app.use(function(req, res) {
   res.status(404);
   res.render('404');
});

// 500 error handler (middleware)
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   console.error(err.stack);
   res.status(500);
   res.render('500');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   console.log('Express started on http://localhost:' + app.get('port') + '; press Ctrl-C to terminate.');
});
```

main.handlebars (main template):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
   <title>Meadowlark Travel</title>
   {{#if showTexts}}
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/mocha.css">
   {{/if}}
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js" integrity="sha256-jrPLZ+8vDxt2FnE1zvZXCkCcebI/C8Dt5xyaQBjxQIo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <header><img src="/img/logo.png" alt="Meadowlark Travel logo"></header>
   {{{body}}}

   {{#if showTests}}
      <div id="mocha"></div>
      <script src="/vendor/mocha.js"></script>
      <script src="/vendor/chai.js"></script>
      <script>
         mocha.ui('tdd');
         var assert = chai.assert;
      </script>
      <script src="/qa/tests-global.js"></script>
      {{#if pageTestScript}}
         <script src="{{pageTestScript}}"></script>
      {{/if}}
      <script>mocha.run();</script>
   {{/if}}
</body>
</html>
```

public/qa/tests-global.js (location of Mocha tests):

```
suite('Global Tests', function() {
   test('page has a valid title', function() {
      assert(document.title && document.title.match(/\S/) &&  
         document.title.toUpperCase() !=== 'TODO');
   }); 
});
```

Folder Structure:

```
meadowlark.js
node_modules > *node.js/npm*
package.json
public > qa     > tests-global.js
       > vendor > chai.js,
                > mocha.css,
                > mocha.js
views > home.handlebars
      > layouts > main.handlebars
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make it so the Mocha tests show up?  If you need any additional files, ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two spelling mistakes and one syntax error.

In `meadowlark.js`, change `req.qurey.text` to `req.query.test`:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.locals.showTests = app.get('env') !== 'production' && req.query.test === '1';
   next();
});
```

In `main.handlebars`, change `{{#if showTexts}}` to `{{#if showTests}}`:

```
{{#if showTests}}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/vendor/mocha.css">
{{/if}}
```

And in `public/qa/tests-global.js`, the not-equals operator should be `!==` rather than `!===`:

```
test('page has a valid title', function() {
  assert(document.title && document.title.match(/\S/) &&  
    document.title.toUpperCase() !== 'TODO');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help, but it still does not work. What should I do now?

Comment: @CDuck I don't know. I tested it on my machine and it's working for me. Did you enter the query string, i.e., `http://localhost:3000/?test=1`? And are there any errors that come up, either in your terminal on the server side, or in the console on the client side?

Comment: OK, I'll need more information then, because it works for me if I make those three changes. What does your directory structure look like?